# Python rapidly leaking memory when Celery retrieves results

Tags: python, memory-leaks, rabbitmq, celery, rpc

The script that I've written to add tasks to the my Celery queue is leaking memory (to the point where the kernel kills the process after 20 minutes). In this script, I'm just executing the same 300 tasks repeatedly, every 60 seconds (inside a `while True:`).

The parameters passed to the task, `makeGroupRequest()`, are dictionaries containing strings, and according to hpy and objgraph, dicts and strings are also what's growing uncontrollably in memory. I've included the outputs of hpy below on successive iterations of the loop.

I've spent days on this, and I can't understand why memory would grow uncontrollably, considering nothing is re-used between loops. If I skip the retrieval of tasks, the memory doesn't appear to leak (so it's really the .get() call that is leaking memory). How can I determine what's going on and how to stop the growth?

Here is an outline of the code that's executing. I'm using the rpc:// backend.

```
while True:

    # preparation is done here to set set up the arguments for the tasks (processedChains)

    chains = []

    for processedChain in processedChains:

        # shorthanding
        supportingData = processedChain["supportingDataAndCheckedGroups"]

        # init the first element, which includes the supportingData and the first group
        argsList = [(supportingData, processedChain["groups"][0])]

        # add in the rest of the groups
        argsList.extend([(groupInChain,) for groupInChain in processedChain["groups"][1:]])

        # actually create the chain
        chain = celery.chain(*[makeGroupRequest.signature(params, options={'queue':queue}) for params in argsList])

        # add this to the list of chains
        chains.append(chain)

    groupSignature = celery.group(*chains).apply_async()

    # this line appears to cause a large increase in memory each cycle
    results = groupSignature.get(timeout = 2 * acceptableLoopTime)

    time.sleep(60)
```

Here is the output of `hpy` on sucessive runs:

Loop 2:

```
Partition of a set of 366560 objects. Total size = 57136824 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  27065   7 17665112  31  17665112  31 dict (no owner)
     1 122390  33 11966720  21  29631832  52 unicode
     2  89133  24  8291952  15  37923784  66 str
     3  45448  12  3802968   7  41726752  73 tuple
     4    548   0  1631072   3  43357824  76 dict of module
     5  11195   3  1432960   3  44790784  78 types.CodeType
     6   9224   3  1343296   2  46134080  81 list
     7  11123   3  1334760   2  47468840  83 function
     8   1414   0  1274552   2  48743392  85 type
     9   1414   0  1240336   2  49983728  87 dict of type
```

Loop 3:

```
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  44754   9 29240496  37  29240496  37 dict (no owner)
     1 224883  44 20946280  26  50186776  63 unicode
     2  89104  18  8290248  10  58477024  74 str
     3  45455   9  3803288   5  62280312  79 tuple
     4  14955   3  2149784   3  64430096  81 list
     5    548   0  1631072   2  66061168  83 dict of module
     6  11195   2  1432960   2  67494128  85 types.CodeType
     7  11122   2  1334640   2  68828768  87 function
     8   1402   0  1263704   2  70092472  88 type
     9   1402   0  1236976   2  71329448  90 dict of type
```

Comment: What is each task returning?  The likelihood is is that the you're tasks are returning values that are too large for the producer to reconsume.

Comment: Each task is constructing a dictionary, and then appending that dictionary to a list and returning that list (the list is passed on to the next task in the chain). I just printed out the size of the return value, and it grows from ~539 bytes to ~12890 bytes in a given cycle (i.e. first task completed has a return value of 539 bytes, last has return value of 12890 bytes). Should I not be manually passing results along the chain? I've done with another script and didn't have a memory leak. How can I test to see if your guess is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in Celery. Switching to the `memcache` backend completely resolves the memory leak. Hopefully the [issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5344#issuecomment-470269831) will be resolved in a subsequent version.